# Using JSTL url and param tag

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a list of sizes that a user can choose from, is it posssible to build a parameter based on a link a user clicks?

For example, there is this following html

```
    <ul class="options list-unstyled">
                <h4 class="m_9">Select a Size</h4>
                <li><a href="?size=s">S</a></li>
                <li><a href="?size=m">M</a></li>
                <li><a href="?size=l">L</a></li>
                <li><a href="?size=xl">XL</a></li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>    
            </ul>
```

And then there is this in my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addprodtocart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView cart(@RequestParam("productId") Integer id, @RequestParam("size") String size) {}
```

Disregarding the productId for now I would like the size requestParam to be equal to which ever one the user clicked.  Basically a temp variable in jstl that changes whenever a new size is selected and then the form below will be passed the built url (basically whichever size the user selected)

```
 <form  method='POST' action="${url }" >  
               <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>  
                 <input type="submit" value="add to cart" title="">
              </form>
```

Is this possible? and how? thank  you

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. Links are for navigation. Radio Buttons, Check boxes and Select are all standard HTML components for allowing the user to select from a list of options.

Comment: Hello I would like the request param to be different based on which button the user clicks. For example of they click small then it should be "mywebsite/?size=s" but if they click say medium before they click "add to cart" then the url should change to "mywebsite/?size=m" does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: you can pass any value to your hidden using jquery or javascript.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like to avoid Javascript/jquery If possible. Thank you